# SOBO using JWT functionality

Tags: docusignapi

we are migrating from legacy authentication to OAuth and I came accross [this article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-oauth-20-and-the-new-sobo). To get the user apiUserName, the post proposes using the [users endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/connect/connectconfigurations/listusers/). Since this link is designed to be used with Connect, I assume this is an unintentional error. Is it necessary for our company to purchase Connect in order to get information about our account's users? We use the account users API [endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/list/) in our integration, and I'm wondering if we were obtaining the erroneous user information all along? Although the post mentions apiUserName multiple times, we don't believe either of the edpoints returns this key. "userName" - my name  and "userId" - my user GUID - are the closest we can get. How and where can we retrieve the value of apiUserName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: You're doing everything right, the post has a mistake and could be clearer.

### Users:list API method

Yes, you should use the [Users:list](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/list/) API method to look up the user's guid ID from their email (or from their name).

The blog post is referencing the wrong API method, I will have it updated.

### UserId or apiUserName

The API and the eSignature Admin application use the term `User ID` or `userId`. In the past, there were some uses of the term `API User Name`.

All of these terms mean the same thing, the guid-form ID for a user within an account.

I will have the blog post updated to clarify this too.

Comment: Larry, thank you for the clarifications. Including a statement that apiUserName is actually a userID in terms of JWT will go a long way toward preventing future misunderstandings.